# Google Apps Script: onEdit breaks on SpreadsheetApp.openById() - Need input on Installable onEdit() Trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I have a Spreadsheet with the following data's in each column, "A_email", "B_file_id", "C_Status", "D_Action" and "E_Result". I framed a script to add/remove editors (email - A column) on the google spreadsheets listed (File ID - B Column) based on the value in field "Status" (Enable/Disable - C Column). I can able to execute the desired function for all the rows (around 250) with the conventional script. But, I need to update only a particular row and so, i modified the script with onedit() trigger. The script fails on the line SpreadsheetApp.openById(). I came to know that i have to use onEdit() as Installable Triggers. As I am a beginner in Coding, Can anyone help me out to get the following corrected?

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var myRange = sheet.getRange("D2:D5"); 
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();

  if (col >= myRange.getColumn() && col <= myRange.getLastColumn() && row >= myRange.getRow() && row <= myRange.getLastRow()) { 
    var file_id = sheet.getRange(row,2).getValue();
    var status = sheet.getRange(row,3).getValue();
    var action = sheet.getRange(row,4).getValue();
    var email = sheet.getRange(row,1).getValue();
    
    var file_1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file_id);

    if (action == "Enable") {
      const add_editor = [email];                                                   
      file_1.addEditors(add_editor); 
    }
    else if(action == "Disable"){
      var editors = file_1.getEditors();
      for (j = 0; j < editors.length; j++) {
        file_1.removeEditor(editors[j]);
      } 
    }   
    var update_range = sheet.getRange(row, 5).setValue("Updated");
  } 
}

function createSpreadsheetEditTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onEdit')
    .forSpreadsheet(ss)
    .onEdit()
    .create();
}
```

I can't able to grasp the concept through https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#new-editor

Comment: When you use the installable OnEdit trigger, I would like to recommend to rename the function name from `onEdit` to others. Because the function name of `onEdit` is used for the simple trigger. So when the installable OnEdit trigger is installed to the function of `onEdit`, this function is run 2 times with the asynchronous processing. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/88f7fd5ed14da5e9afde18310da61cb5) So please be careful this.

Comment: What's the error you get when it fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Step 1:

Rename `onEdit(e)` to a different name for example `myFunction(e)` since you want to create an installable trigger and not a simple one. Your code can be improved a little bit to take advantage of the event object. **Don't**  execute `myFunction(e)` as this will be a trigger function, namely it will be executed (triggered) itself upon edits. You will get errors if you execute it manually and it won't work anyways.

```
function myFunction(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();

  // change "Sheet1" to the specific name
  if (sheet.getName() == "Sheet1" && col == 4 && row >= 2 && row <= 5) { 
    var file_id = sheet.getRange(row,2).getValue();
    var status = sheet.getRange(row,3).getValue();
    var action = sheet.getRange(row,4).getValue();
    var email = sheet.getRange(row,1).getValue();
    
    var file_1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file_id);

    if (action == "Enable") {
      const add_editor = [email];                                                   
      file_1.addEditors(add_editor); 
    }
    else if(status == "Disable"){
      var editors = file_1.getEditors();
      for (j = 0; j < editors.length; j++) {
        file_1.removeEditor(editors[j]);
      } 
    }   
    var update_range = sheet.getRange(row, 5).setValue("Updated");
  } 
}
```

Please note here I added an extra checker `sheet.getName() == "Sheet1"` to ensure that the script will run the code inside the `if` only upon edits on `"Sheet1"`. Change that to the name of your sheet you want to work with or remove this condition if you want to apply your script to every sheet in the document.

### Step 2:

Execute **only** the following function **one** time. You don't want to create multiple triggers for the same function. Also make sure to clear all currently created `onEdit` triggers you may have accidentally created. And execute **only** and **once** the following:

```
function createSpreadsheetEditTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
    .forSpreadsheet(ss)
    .onEdit();
}
```

After both steps, the block of code under the main `if` statement will be executed upon edits on the range `D2:D4` in the sheet `"Sheet1"`.

> How to execute the particular function alone?

Just select the function you want to run and click the play button:

[image]

> how to clear all currently created onEdit triggers?

Click on the current project's triggers:

[image]

and delete all the triggers you see in this list (if any).

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation, I am totally clear with step 1. In step 2, How to execute the particular function alone (Shall i need to create a new .gs file and run it alone?). Also, can you tell me how to clear all currently created onEdit triggers? (accidentally created). Thank you in advance. @Marios